# Why should already negative sentences have 'no' in them again ?

Tags: grammar

I encountered a couple of sentences, mostly in American movies, that I wondered why they have something I call ' Double negatives', for example:

> Don't go **no** further (why not Don't go further)
>
> We can't grow **no** crops without **no** water
>
> I don't see **no** friends (why not I don't see *any* friends / I see no friends)

What's the structure of these sentences, are these considered informal? Are there any other correct alternatives to them?

Comment: The question has been raised several times, often in forms which were closed as duplicates of the question linked above. Some others are http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/there-isnt-nowhere-id-rather-be-than-here-with-you/1201#1201, http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11352/aint-no-is-this-not-a-double-negation, and http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/is-this-a-double-negation-or-a-dialect